# Confused with eth transaction pick up priority

Tags: transactions, mining, pending-transactions, fees

I've added a transaction couple days ago at 8 gwei with little priority fee (0.001) There were blocks where the base fee was lower than mine yet it wasn't picked up. This is one recent [example block](https://etherscan.io/txs?block=19108274)

After going through transactions in the block I noticed some txs had even lower base fees and no priority fees neither. I'm willing to pay more than several users here and it's not picked up if so what are the criteria to be included? Some additional info on my tx that might help, it's not a simple call to transfer eth or erc20 tokens, I'm staking tokens on a defi platform and gas limit is set to 800k.